# C# NHibernate architecture, three tier application

Tags: c#, nhibernate, architecture, unit-of-work

I need some advice how we can decouple nHibernate dependencies in the presentation layer. Currently we have a three tier C# winforms application consisting (simplified) of the following layers;

- User Interface (UI)
- Business Logic (BAL)
- Data Access Logic (DAL)

We are migrating this application to an ORM (nHibernate) and would ideally like to have only the DAL referencing nHibernate. We also want to employ the "Unit of Work" functionality which is included in nHibernate, adopting a "Session per conversation" methodology.

To achieve this we need to create and open a session in the UI, pass the session through the BAL to the DAL however we cannot achieve this without creating a dependency to nHibernate in both the BAL and DAL.

Any advice would be appreciated. How should we structure the architecture to avoid any references to nHibernate in the UI and BAL. Any ideas?

I must also add that we do not want the UI to have a reference to the DAL either.

UI => BAL => DAL

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't really make sense (although I do understand what you are trying to accomplish as I've been there).  It may be doable, but it will potentially be difficult to understand the implementation details and it provides very little value in return.  My recommendation: Allow your UI layer to know about NHibernate, but minimize the usage of NHibernate in that layer.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to do it that way, since the UnitOfWork pattern is implemented by NHibernate's Session object.
However, you only want to reference NHibernate from your DAL, which is quite useless, since your DAL doesn't know anything about the application's context, and this context is necessary in order to use the UnitOfWork.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book) I found it quite useful for getting to grips with NHibernate.

You will need to extract your entities and create POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects). Your UI will not require any knowledge of NHibernate. You will create methods in your Data Layer to manipulate your data.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your IoC container in a separate class library, for example by using the "GuyWire" pattern described here:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/11/07/nhibernate-and-wpf-the-guywire.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recently built an example of a decoupled architecture using nhibernate in an asp.net mvc application. It uses a repository pattern and a separate unit of work. Most of these concepts should be reusable in a thick client also. Here is a search link on my blog with the posts that may be interesting.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/?s=Nhibernate

Hope this gets you started. Let me know if you have questions.

Bob

Comment: Thanks Bob, Just having a read through this blog of yours http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/ and I notice that your test layer will need to have a dependency to NHibernateHelper. As the test project is akin to the UI layer, are you saying that the UI layer needs a reference to the ORM project which in our case would be the DAL.

Comment: I use an IOC container to create the nhibernate instance of the repos. This is done in the app start up. This is the only class that references the nhibernate libs. All other areas of the app reference the repo interfaces. The important thing is that the nhibernate specific code is isolated to one area.

Comment: If you configure the IoC container in a separate class library ("GuyWire" pattern), which is invoked via reflection, then you can eliminate even this single reference from the UI layer to NH libs.

Comment: I agree that it is possible. You still need to have the type specified in a config file and deploy the dlls. This provider pattern has the benefit of being able to hot wire the repo. There is added complexity and if you don't have the need for multiple types of repos, I choose the less complex solution (IMO).